# Standard Update Urls

Tags: updates, 13.10

What are the standard update URLs for Ubuntu 13.10. For example, is this a standard one:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu
```

?

By *standard*  I mean those update sources that are added by default when one installs a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PPA's are *never* part of the sources when you install a fresh copy of *any* Ubuntu as of 13.10. To get the standard sources, go to your dash, type "Software sources". In the window that pops up, make sure they are as shown in the screenshots:

[image: ubuntu softwares]

You can choose the server that is best for your needs. And if you want, you can choose the "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" ones, if you need drivers for your graphics card, sound card, etc. You may most probably not need the source code(unless you are into learning how these programs have been written).

[image: other softwares]

In the above screenshot, you may see different PPA's than mine, don't worry, you don't need to select them to have the default sources.

[image: updates]

Check for updates depending on your needs.